# arrange an array of integers in ascending or descending order using the Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of integers in Python, but I am encountering some difficulties. I have tried multiple approaches, but none of them seem to be working. Here is the code that I have attempted:

```py
my_array = [5, 2, 8, 1, 9]

sorted_array = my_array.sort()

print(sorted_array)
```

I expected the code above to print the sorted array, but instead, it gives me `None` as the output. I'm unsure why this is happening.

I have also tried using the built-in `sorted()` function, like this:

```py
my_array = [5, 2, 8, 1, 9]

sorted_array = sorted(my_array)

print(sorted_array)
```

However, this code produces the same result - `None` as the output. I have confirmed that the array is not empty and contains integers.

Comment: The `sorted` code [does not print what you say it prints](https://ideone.com/4TQVOU).

Answer (score 1):

**`my_array.sort` sorts the list "in place":**

Instead of returning a sorted list, as you seem to expect, `my_array.sort()` sorts `my_array` "in place" and doesn't return anything. Try this

```
my_array = [5, 2, 8, 1, 9]
my_array.sort()
print(my_array)  # [1, 2, 5, 8, 9]
```

If you want it sorted in descending order use this:

```
my_array = [5, 2, 8, 1, 9]
my_array.sort()
my_array.reverse()
print(my_array)  # [9, 8, 5, 2, 1]
```